# How to make header urls independent?

Tags: python, django

I have `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
        path('video/<int:video_n>', views.video_detail, name='video_detail'),
        path('mylink1', views.mylink1, name = 'mylink1'),
    ]
```

It's ok for my url `mysite.com/video/12345`

I have nav bar in header `video_detail.html`

```
<header>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="mylink1">link 1</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

I want only links from header navbar (`link 1`) redirects to `mysite.com/mylink1`

But django engine redirects me to `mysite.com/video/mylink1`

How to avoid wrong redirect or make nav url independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you used didn't give the url by `name`, you gave string `mylink1`. So,

```
<a href="{% url 'mylink1' %}">link 1</a>
```